# Angular2 RC4 select with default value

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-forms

I have this code to generate a select with Angular2:

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="invoice.customer" formControlName="customer" required>
    <option *ngFor="let cus of customers" [ngValue]="cus">
        {{cus.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

invoice is an object with a customer field (which is an object with fields like "name", "street", "city" etc.)

The select is created correctly and if I select a customer from the dropdown it is saved in "`invoice.customer`" like it should be.

This is fine for creating a new invoice, but if I want to edit an invoice I want the customer in invoice.customer set as default.

"selected" doesn't work, as far as I understand it gets ignored because of the 2-way databinding.

"invoice" (with invoice.customer) is set in the ngOnInit method via a http-request and every other formcontrol (inputfields etc) is filled correctly with the data from it.

I use `"@angular/forms": "0.2.0"` if there is something new.

I guess this should be simple, but I can't get it to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The value of `invoide.customer` is selected automatically. You can try `[value]="cus"` instead of `ngValue`. `ngValue` is only necessary if `cus` is an object. For string values `value` is fine. Otherwise I guess this needs a Plunker because it is probably caused by subtle details that can't be derived from the provided information.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks for the fast answer. cus is an object so value doesn't work. But I'm trying to create a plnkr, but everything works as intended right now inside the plnkr, so I have to try some more until I have the same results in app as in plnkr. (favorably the app works as the plnkr)

Comment: If `cus` is an object than `invoice.customer` also needs to be an object. In fact for a default value, it needs to be the same object instance as the `[ngValue]="..."` that it should match. It's not enough if the objects have the same properties with the same values.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer yep, I guess that is the problem respectively it is the difference between the plnkr and my app.
the plnkr: [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/gdNcPA684NNQQ78yvJTk)

Should have known, I will have to try a different approach, thanks!

Comment: @derpawe I'm having the same problem, can you share the solution ?

Comment: @user1431866 I'm sorry, I haven't really solved that, as it is/was low priority. Maybe you can try to compare the values of the object yourself and overwrite the saved object with the correct object from the array.